# How to initialize recyclerview in fragment which uses cardview and constraint layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new with using recyclerview and need some help with its initializing. I created test version of recyclerview with constarint layout in it and it worked perfectly when my code ws placed in mainactivity.But now when I copied it to main project to my main Fragment there was shown errors in context.

My code in mainFragment:

```
class MastersFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_masters) {


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        val arrayList = ArrayList<Model>()

        arrayList.add(Model("Sakurami", "This is sakurami", "Aliya Alieva", R.drawable.image_1__2_,
            R.drawable.ic_building_place_of_work, 
R.drawable.ic_btn_not_filled_favourite,R.drawable.ic_circle, "4,7", "Косметолог"))
        arrayList.add(Model("Sakurami", "This is sakurami", "Aliya Alieva", R.drawable.image_1__2_,
            R.drawable.ic_building_place_of_work, 
R.drawable.ic_btn_not_filled_favourite,R.drawable.ic_circle,"4,7", "Косметолог"))
        arrayList.add(Model("Sakurami", "This is sakurami", "Aliya Alieva", R.drawable.image_1__2_,
            R.drawable.ic_building_place_of_work, 
R.drawable.ic_btn_not_filled_favourite,R.drawable.ic_circle, "4,7", "Косметолог"))
        arrayList.add(Model("Sakurami", "This is sakurami", "Aliya Alieva", R.drawable.image_1__2_,
            R.drawable.ic_building_place_of_work, 
R.drawable.ic_btn_not_filled_favourite,R.drawable.ic_circle,"4,7","Косметолог"))
        arrayList.add(Model("Sakurami", "This is sakurami", "Aliya Alieva", R.drawable.image_1__2_,
            R.drawable.ic_building_place_of_work, 
R.drawable.ic_btn_not_filled_favourite,R.drawable.ic_circle, "4,7", "Косметолог"))
        arrayList.add(Model("Sakurami", "This is sakurami", "Aliya Alieva", R.drawable.image_1__2_,
            R.drawable.ic_building_place_of_work, 
R.drawable.ic_btn_not_filled_favourite,R.drawable.ic_circle,"4,7", "Косметолог"))
        arrayList.add(Model("Sakurami", "This is sakurami", "Aliya Alieva", R.drawable.image_1__2_,
            R.drawable.ic_building_place_of_work, 
R.drawable.ic_btn_not_filled_favourite,R.drawable.ic_circle, "4,7", "Косметолог"))

        val masterAdapter = MasterAdapter(arrayList, this)

        master_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(**this**)
        master_recyclerview.adapter = masterAdapter

    }

}
```

error is in LinearLayoutManager(this)

So the problem is in linearlayut manager and in master adapter(make text error). What is the solution? Is there anything which can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You re executing the code inside a fragment so you need to use requireContext() instead of this

`master_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())`

also in your masteradapter line pass the same context requireContext()

`val masterAdapter = MasterAdapter(arrayList, requireContext())`

Comment: In addition, unless you're going to do anything special with the LinearLayoutManager, it's the default and you can/should put it in the XML directly, e.g.: in your <RecyclerView... add `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` (if you're using AndroidX, ortherwise use the path to the `support` version).